# Wordpress showing directory url with hashtag link

Tags: wordpress, url

I've stumbled on this strange issue that I never had before; 
On my website that is based on Wordpress, I have a link with a href="#". What it should do is this http://example.com/**#** but what it does is this http://example.com/**wp-content/themes/exampletheme/#**. This gives a 404 of cours because it doesn't exist.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem? I got access to other Wordpress based websites and tested it but didn't got this issue.

Comment: Could you perhaps show us a little code?

Comment: thats completely weird issue perhaps a little code might give us a clue..

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know how it happend. If I put <a href="#">test</a> in the (for example) header.php file it generates this url: http://example.com/wp-content/themes/exampletheme/# instead of http://example.com/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some testing and found out it had to do with the following code in the header.php:

```
<base href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/">
```